# Where is the convolution of two functions well defined?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, convolution

I want to mollify a function $f\in L^1_{loc}(\Omega)$, $\Omega$ open in $\mathbb R^n$. So, we take a sequence of standard mollifiers $\{\phi_\epsilon\}$, for example, and do the convolution $f*\phi_\epsilon$.

I've read that, if $\Omega$ is not the whole $\mathbb R^n$, $f*\phi_\epsilon(x)$ is well defined for all $x\in \Omega$ such that $0<\epsilon<d(x,\partial \Omega)$: does this mean that $u_\epsilon$ is well defined only for that $x$'s? If it were so, I wouldn't understand why. I see that if $x\in \Omega$ and if $d(x,\partial \Omega)<\epsilon$, then $\text{supp }\phi_{\epsilon}(\,x-\cdot\,)$ is not entirely contained in $\Omega$. Is this a problem? When I have to write down the integral I get $$f*\phi_\epsilon(x):=\int_\Omega \phi_\epsilon(x-y)f(y)dy=\int_{\Omega\cap \overline{B(x,\epsilon)}} \phi_\epsilon(x-y)f(y),$$

so, even if $x\in \Omega$ but $d(x,\partial \Omega)<\epsilon$, $u_\epsilon(x)$ seems well defined to me.
What's wrong? Where's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not a problem. What you are doing is to extend $f$ by setting it equal to $0$ outside of $\Omega$ and then doing the convolution with the extension.

Comment: So, the convolution $f*\phi_{\epsilon}(x)$ is indeed well defined even for those $x$ s.t. $d(x,\partial \Omega)<\epsilon$, right?

Comment: Not with the original definition, since $f$ is not defined outside $\Omega$. What you are doing is giving a definition for those $x$ such that $d(x,\partial\Omega)<\epsilon$. But there are more ways to define it: every locally integrable extension of $f$ outside of $\Omega$ will give one. For instance, if you knew that $f=1$ on $\partial\Omega$, it would seem reasonable to extend $f$ as $1$ outside $\Omega$.

Comment: Ok, now it is clearer! Thank you. So, if I don't want to extend $f$ outside $\Omega$ at all, in order to define $f*\phi_\epsilon$, I'm forced to take $x\in \Omega$ s.t. $d(x,\partial \Omega)>\epsilon$.

Comment: Yes, that's it.